# Kannel Round Robin Setup when SMSC is absent in sendsms Query String

Tags: kannel

I want to make a Round Robin configuration setting in the Kannel for the below message sending given that I have 2 SMSC(SMSC0 and SMSC1). When no SMSC is present in the query string, I like to use SMSC0 and SMSC1 in a Round Robin fashion. This is something like making a Default SMSC setting that will handle those things not explicitly handled by any SMSC. May be ***denied-smsc-id***, ***allowed-smsc-id***, ***preferred-smsc-id*** have some role.

```
cgi-bin/sendsms?username=sendsms&password=sendsms&to=44897742898855&from=test100&text=testmessagesinfohello&dlr-mask=31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NOT ROUND-ROBIN:
================
group = smsc
smsc-id = smsc1
allowed-smsc-id = smsc1

group = smsc
smsc-id = smsc2
allowed-smsc-id = smsc2

group = sendsms-user
default-smsc = smsc1

ROUND-ROBIN:
================
group = smsc
smsc-id = smsc1
denied-smsc-id = smsc2

group = smsc
smsc-id = smsc2
denied-smsc-id = smsc1
```